# R "colorfindr" package error : get_colors() is not working with JPEG files?

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract colors frequencies from `JPEG files` :

```
library(colorfindr)
my_path <- "C://Users/Rayane_2/Desktop/Data/PCB1/PCB/PCB_USED/02.jpg"
get_colors(my_path)
```

The previous code gives the following error / I got this error only with `.JPG` files :

```
Error in read_from_path(file) : 
  Argument 'file' must be a file path, or url.
```

The `get_colors()` is `working correctly with .png files` :

```
pic1 <- system.file("extdata", "pic1.png", package = "colorfindr")
pic1
[1] "C:/Users/Rayane_2/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/colorfindr/extdata/pic1.png"
> get_colors(pic1)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  col_hex col_freq col_share
  <chr>      <int>     <dbl>
1 #FF7F27    20000       0.5
2 #FFFFFF    20000       0.5
```

Comment: Could it be the double forward slash in `"C://Users/Rayane_2/Desktop/Data/PCB1/PCB/PCB_USED/02.jpg"`?

Comment: I removed the additional slash / , i even tried get_colors(file.path(my_path)) without success

Comment: Have you tried `file.exists(my_path)` to ensure this is not a problem with the path?

Comment: Very good point ;)

Comment: File was moved from initial directory